# Double negative: "Didn't I say that I didn't want any trouble?"

Tags: grammar, double-negation

Does the above sentence make sense? It's meant to be rhetorical.

Comment: This doesn't immediately strike me as the typical double negative. It makes perfect sense to me.

Comment: Yes, a double negative is a statement saying not (not X). Making your original into a statement rather than a question to make comparison easier ('I didn't say that I didn't want any trouble'), you have a statement saying you didn't make an earlier statement saying not X.

Comment: The above sentence makes perfect sense, but it's not a double negative. A real double negative would be *"Didn't I say I didn't want no trouble?"*

Comment: And a simpler one would be _I didn't want no trouble_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth But changing it into a statement 'I didn't say I didn't want any trouble' does create a double negative. I am not sure you make that clear. And what does that do to the original question?

Comment: @WS2 I'm going with the stricter and to my mind more useful definition given [here](http://www.accu-assist.com/grammar-tips-archive/GrammarTip_double-negatives.htm): 'A double negative occurs only when there are two negative words in the same clause.' Which follows: ... 'Myth #1: _Never use more than one negative word in a sentence._
A negative word affects only the clause in which it is located, not the entire sentence. In other words, you may use one negative expression in each clause.'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has two negative clauses (Didn't I tell you AND I didn't want any trouble) but, no, it's not a "double negative".